# Data getting lost after refresh JavaScript-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, page-refresh

Local storage is getting cleared after refresh tried many StackOverflow solutions but none are solving it. Please help:

Code:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    retrivedTasks();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    saveToLocal();
  }, [tasks]);

  const saveToLocal = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
  };

  const retrivedTasks = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("tasks") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      let dataFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
      setTasks(dataFromLS);
    }
  };
```

Comment: *tried many StackOverflow solutions* like which ones? just so we don't suggest them again

Comment: Have you tried reading from ```localStorage``` when setting initial state value for ```tasks```?

Comment: The only way your entry in local storage get cleared is via `saveToLocal` method. Could it be that your empty tasks overwrite the local storage entry *before* local storage get the chance to restore your `tasks`?

Comment: @DamodarHegde the "retrivedTasks()" method is the one that I created to get tasks from the localstorage when the app launches for the first time.

Comment: This is what I meant ```const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));```